# change unselected option as selected in selec2 multi select

Tags: jquery

I have multiple select box which is used to create a group with multiple items
my problem is when some item given in the list is not selected it shuld be defaultly assignend to `group1` so that I got the unselected items in each group but I cant make it as selected in `group1`

I tried this code

```
$('select#group1 option[value="' + unselectvalue + '"]').prop("selected",true);
```

but this is not working

select shows only the item i selected already

I just want to add the new item into existing selected item

Comment: Try to trigger `change` event on the select after editing it

Comment: Add snippet example

Comment: Try to put your full source code please

Comment: Here is the code
$('select.group_channel').find('option:not(:selected):not([disabled])').each(function() {
                    console.log($(this).val());
                    $('select#group1 > option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop("selected",true);
                    $('select#group1').each(function() {
                        $(this).find('option:selected').each(function() {
                            console.log($(this).val());
                        });
                    });
                });

Comment: i got a solution thank you